# Fragment with compatibility pack and > honeycomb

Tags: android, android-activity, compatibility, android-fragments, fragment

I have to write an app for both phones and tablets and I would like to use the same project for both. It seems the use of compatibility library is good to write reusable code.

Is possible to share the same Fragment class for both?

I'm thinking about a starting activity that "forks" the app in pre-honeycomb activities and post-honeycomb, reusing the same Fragment classes. The fact is if I include android.app.Fragment, the fragment will not be usable from a FragmentActivity and viceversa.
I could use only FragmentActivities, but this would prevent the use of the actionbar.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in the example [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Contacts/Spinners/) does not seem to be appropriate.
For contacts the problem is that there is a class that is deprecated but you can still compile it.
With fragment if you refer to android.app.Fragment you can't compile that class with the sdk < 3.0 while if use import android.support.v4.app.Fragment you can't compile for honeycomb (you can only if you keep using the support lib even on honeycomb that does not seem to be the best thing to do).

I managed to do it only by having two different projects that expose two different implementations of a proxy. Than I use the right implementation for each sdk. It is not as simple as it looks because you will have to make a proxy for FragmentTransaction, FragmentManager etc.

It worked for me but it did not work for settings with fragment. In that case the xml files that use fragment can't be compiled with pre honeycomb sdk.

Comment: Hmm it seems now working, using different activities for phones and tablets and using the same Fragments from android.support.v4.app.Fragment. The ActionBar code is managed by tablets' activities only.

Using min_sdk = 7 and target_sdk=13, using sdk 13 libs does the trick!

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: but this means that you are using the support lib on honeycomb too, right? And what about settings? How can you have two different implementation without using two separated lib?

Comment: I simply use the support library also on honeycomb and it seems to works fine. I manage the fragments only inside code, not xml.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can share the same Fragment class for both. You don't want to be touching actionbar code on the phone (pre-honeycomb) so an easy way is to simply hide your actionbar code in an adapter class that you  only make use of in your Fragment for honeycomb+, see answer [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Contacts/Spinners/).

One thing that you can then do is make use of version/size specific resoures such as menu, menu-v11 etc to add say menu items to either your action bar on a tablet or the standard menu pop-up on a phone.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) which is a compatibility library that integrates and builds on Google's own compatibility library but provides backwards-compatibility for the Action Bar as well as fragments and all that other good stuff.

It uses the native ActionBar classes provided by API 13+ so the code should be re-usable for your "forks" (or you may not have to fork as much/at all).

Worth having a browse of the website...